# Django displays `TourCategory object` string instead of TourCategory's name

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class New(models.Model):
.....
category = models.ForeignKey(TourCategory, verbose_name="Tour Category")
```

in browser

```
<select id="id_category" name="category">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">TourCategory object</option>
<option value="2">TourCategory object</option>
<option value="3">TourCategory object</option>
</select>
```

Model TourCategory

```
from django.db import models

class TourCategory(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Name")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Tour Category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Tour categories'
```

The goal to make it displayed the names of TourCategory

Comment: post the code related to TourCategory model.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the description, which is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses Class' `__unicode__` method (or `__str__` method if you are not using unicode) to display `object representation` of that object.

Django uses this methods to display objects in admin site.

So you have to define or fix `__unicode__` (or `__str__`)

```
class TourCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Name")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[Look here for the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str) . Normally you should not need to cast
`self.name` to `unicode`, but I write it so you can test with and without it.